# Creating graph for an absorbing markov chain

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I have the problem to create the following graph
[image]

It should have the following style
[image]

The code is given by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,automata,positioning} 
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}} % natuerliche Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} % ganze Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}} % rationale Zahlen
    \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} % reelle Zahlen
    \newcommand{\Prob}{\mathbb{P}} % Symbol fuer Wahrscheinlichkeitsmaß
    \newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}} % Symbol fuer Erwartungswert
    \newcommand{\QAt}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{2}}}
    \newcommand{\QAo}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{1}}}
    \newcommand{\QAot}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{2}}}
    \newcommand{\QAto}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{1}}}
    \newcommand{\QAtC}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}C}}
    \newcommand{\QAtw}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}}
    \newcommand{\QAow}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}}
    \newcommand{\I}{\mathbf{I}}
    \newcommand{\vf}{\mathbf{v}}
    \newcommand{\Df}{\mathbf{D}}
    \newcommand{\af}{\pmb{\alpha}}
    \newcommand{\eef}{\mathbf{e}}
    \newcommand{\Psf}{\pmb{\Psi}}
    \newcommand{\Phf}{\pmb{\Phi}}
    \newcommand{\bef}{\pmb{\beta}}
    \newcommand{\Pf}{\mathbf{P}}
    \newcommand{\Qf}{\mathbf{Q}}
    \newcommand{\mf}{\mathbf{m}}
    \newcommand{\ef}{\pmb{\varepsilon}}
    \newcommand{\Hf}{\mathbf{H}}
    \newcommand{\Ef}{\mathbf{E}}
    \newcommand{\Mf}{\mathbf{M}}
    \newcommand{\Vf}{\mathbf{V}}
    \newcommand{\gf}{\mathbf{g}}
    \newcommand{\QSo}{\mathbf{Q}_{S' S'}}
    \newcommand{\QSot}{\mathbf{Q}_{S' S''}}
    \newcommand{\QSt}{\mathbf{Q}_{S'' S''}}
    \newcommand{\UP}[2]{\makebox[0pt]{\smash{\raisebox{1.5em}{$\phantom{#2}#1$}}}#2}
    \newcommand{\LF}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{$#1$\hspace{4.5em}}}
    \newcommand{\zfo}{\mathbf{z}_{1}}
    \newcommand{\zft}{\mathbf{z}_{2}}
    \newcommand{\zf}{\mathbf{z}}
\begin{document}}


    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
                        semithick]
      \tikzset{every state/.append style={fill=red,draw=none,text=white}}

      \node[state]         (A)                    {$\{\omega\}$};
      \node[state]         (B) [below=of A] {$A_{2}(1)$};
      \node[state]         (C) [below=of B] {$A_{1}(1)$};
      \node[state]         (D) [below=of C] {$\{\omega\}$};
      \node[state]         (F) [right=of B] {$A_{2}(2)$};
      \node[state]         (E) [above=of F] {$\{\omega\}$};
      \node[state]         (G) [below=of F] {$A_{1}(2)$};
      \node[state]         (H) [below=of G] {$\{\omega\}$};
      \node[state]         (J) [right=of F] {$A_{2}(m)$};
      \node[state]         (I) [above=of J] {$\{\omega\}$};
      \node[state]         (K) [below=of J] {$A_{1}(m)$};
      \node[state]         (L) [below=of K] {$\{\omega\}$};
      \node[state]         (M) [right=of J] {$A_{2}$\scriptsize(m+1)};


      \path (B) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (A)
                edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (B)
                edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (C)
            (C) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (C)
                edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (D)
                edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (F)
            (F) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (E)
                edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (F)
                edge              node(aux) {$\QAto$}                        (G)
            (G) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (G)
                edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (H)
            (J) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (I)
                edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (J)
                edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (K)
            (K) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (K)
                edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (L)
                edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (M)
            (M) edge [loop left]  node {$\I$}                           (M);
     \node[right=2mm of aux,font=\bfseries\Huge]{\dots};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I'am Sorry...I have edited my question

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not compile, there is no documentclass etc.

Comment: Why is this so important for you? I only want to create the graph at the top using tikz

Comment: A working example gives the people who are trying to help you something to start with. Setting up a document boring and might deter people from starting to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some starting point:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  auto,
  node distance = 14mm,
  start chain = going right,
  state/.append style = {
      thick, 
      minimum width=3em,
      on chain,
  fill=red,
  draw=none,
  text=white
 },
]

\node (s0)[state]    {$1$};   
\node (s1)[state]    {$2$};  
\node (s2)[state]    {$3$};  
\node (s3)[state]    {$r-2$};  
\node (s4)[state]    {$r-1$};     

\draw[->] (s0) edge[bend left] node (a1) {p} (s1)
          (s1) edge[bend left] node (b1) {q} (s0)
          (s1) edge[bend left] node (a2) {p} (s2)
          (s2) edge[bend left] node (b2) {q} (s1)
          (s3) edge[bend left] node (a4) {p} (s4)
          (s4) edge[bend left] node (b4) {q} (s3)
          ;

\node[state,node distance=3cm] (a) [below=of s2] {$\alpha$};      
\draw[->] (s4.south west) edge node {p} (a); 
\draw[<-] (a) edge node {q} (s0.south east); 
\node[node distance=0.3cm,right=of s2] {$\ldots$};  
\path (a) edge [loop below] node {Q} (a);    

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! But how can I add a loop edge to the node $\alpha$ and how to label the edges pointing to $\alpha$?

Comment: @wayne In your graph at the top, there is no loop - and the code of the other one is still not compilable.

Comment: I have forget it. Can you please edit your code so that the edges pointing to \alpha are labeled. And also a loop for the node \alpha

Comment: @wayne Just stick `\node{p}` into the obvious place (that is, before the end point `(a)`) in the last two `\draw` commands. That may not do what you want perfectly, so tweak the positioning of the nodes a bit by saying something like `\node[below]`, `\node[below=2pt]` (moving them 2pt further from the anchor point), or perhaps `\node[below left]` and `\node[below right]`. But really, what you were given is explicitly a *starting point*. The purpose of this site is not to get other people to do your work for you. Rather, it is to get people unstuck when they're stuck.

Comment: @wayne My motivation to invest further work in this answer is very low. There is still no compilable example in your answer and for most of your previous questions users gave you nice answers, but you did not mark any of them as accepted.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will handle it

Comment: @wayne Thanks for accepting the answers to your previous questions! In exchange I added some p and q.

Comment: I have only one question. How can I achieve that the node $\alpha$ also is drawn in a red circle?

Comment: @wayne Will you make the code in your question compilable?

Comment: @samcarter I have fix it. Sorry about the circumstances

Comment: @wayne I adjusted the node style of the \alpha

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** a new version. I have done some changes. You can change the size the character similary where there are a large **p** and and large **1**.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*\nci[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle, draw=red, fill=red, draw,inner sep=7pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\adjustbox{scale=.5,center}{%
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.6in,row sep=1.1in]
\nci{\textcolor{white}{\resizebox{.5cm}{!}{1}}}\arrow[r, "\resizebox{.5cm}{!}{$p$}", bend left=15] \arrow[rrd, "q"'] & \nci{\textcolor{white}{2}} \arrow[l, "q", bend left=15] \arrow[r, "p", bend left=15] & \nci{\textcolor{white}{3}}\cdots  \arrow[l, "q", bend left=15] & \qquad \cdots \nci{\textcolor{white}{$r-2$}} \arrow[r, "p", bend left=10] & \nci{\textcolor{white}{$r-1$}} \arrow[lld, "p"'] \arrow[l, "q", bend left=10] \\
  &  & \alpha &  & 
\end{tikzcd}
}
\end{document}
```

Here a version with [`tikz-cd`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) simply to compare with what you want. Of course you can increase the size of the characters etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.6in,row sep=1.1in]
1 \arrow[r, "p", bend left=15] \arrow[rrd, "q"'] & 2 \arrow[l, "q", bend left=15] \arrow[r, "p", bend left=15] & 3\cdots  \arrow[l, "q", bend left=15] & \qquad \cdots r-2 \arrow[r, "p", bend left=10] & r-1 \arrow[lld, "p"'] \arrow[l, "q", bend left=10] \\
  &  & \alpha &  & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not compile. Can you please add the code using tikzpicture

Comment: @wayne it compiles fine for me on a current texlive2018. Did you actually tried?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses the `chain` concept with TikZ *(see section 19  from page 257 of 3.0.1a manual)*.
The first string defines nodes `1`; `2`; `3`; ...; `n-1` and `n-2`.
The second chain reuses these nodes and places the arrows in the opposite direction.

[image: chaine]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[grow right=20mm,edges=bend left,edge node={node [yshift=3pt, midway]{p}}] {
1 -> 2   -> 3-!-4/$\cdots$   -!- 5/{$n-2$}->6/{$n-1$}  ;
};
\graph[use existing nodes,edges=bend right,grow right=20mm,edge node={node [yshift=3pt, midway]{q}}]  {
1 <- 2   <- 3-!-4/$\cdots$   -!- 5/{$n-2$}<-6/{$n-1$}  ;
};
\node at (5,-2)(a){a}edge [loop below] node {s} ();;
\graph[use existing nodes,edges={bend right=10}]{ 1.south->[edge label'=q](a)<-[edge label=p]6.south;};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how can I add a loop to the node $a$?

Comment: A loop up or down?

Comment: I added a loop below node $a$